# How can I set the cursor position in a WebControl textbox in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, web-controls

I need to set the cursor to the end of a webcontrol textbox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only with JavaScript.on page load event. Just add this code into your  section by provideing id of your textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var oInput = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
    oInput.focus();    
    oInput.value += "";
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on how to do it please, what to rename and where, because I'm pretty new in ASP.NET and I'm not familiar with javascript at all.